# How do we cast an int as a BigInt in Dart 2?

Tags: dart

Playing around with the `BigInt` class in Dart 2 (Dart VM version: 2.0.0-dev.50.0), I came across the following issues:

```
BigInt x = 5;

print(x % 3); // 2
print(x ~/ 3); // 1
```

So far, so good, but...

When I try to access the methods, for example:

```
print(x.pow(2));
```

I get a *NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method 'pow'* exception. It appears that `x` is being treated as a vanilla flavored `int`...

Further, if I try to instantiate `x` more explicitly:

```
var x = new BigInt.from(5);
```

I get *NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance getter '_used'.*

Am I misunderstanding [the documentation](https://api.dartlang.org/dev/2.0.0-dev.50.0/dart-core/BigInt-class.html)? Specifically, how do we cast an `int`, like `5` or `['a', 'b', 'c'].length`, as a `BigInt` object?

Edit: Although this doesn't explain why `BigInt x = 5` and then such expressions as `x % 3` do not generate errors and work as expected, this appears to simply be due to `BigInt`s and `int`s not playing well together. For example, once `x` really does represent a `BigInt` (unlike if it's instantiated using `BigInt x = 5`, after which `x` appears to represent a regular `int`) then the expression `x % 3` doesn't work because the `%` operation is expecting a `BigInt` on the right hand side, which `3` is not. (The expression needs to change to the clunky `x % new BigInt.from(3)` to get rid of the *NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance getter '_used'* exception.)

As I mentioned already, this does not explain everything. The fact that such expressions as `BigInt x = 5` are allowed, and that expressions such as `x % 3` then work as expected suggests that `BigInt`s and `int`s are *meant* to work seamlessly together, at least on some designer's papers...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are running Dart in Dart 1 production mode and without testing your code with the analyzer. That means that you get no type checking, and your program is indeed not type-correct.
The literal `5` is not a `BigInt`, it is an `int`. You are assigning it to a variable typed as `BigInt`, but in Dart 1 production mode, the variable type is ignored, so that "succeeds". 
`BigInt`s and `int`s are not meant to work seamlessly together, but if you don't actually check the types, you won't know that you are using the wrong one.

Your fix, `var x = new BigInt.from(5);`, is correct. Dart does not do implicit conversion, you have to explicitly create a `BigInt` to get one.
That also means that you have to do:

```
var x = new BigInt.from(5);
print(x % new BigInt.from(3)); // 2
```

That code *should* work. so if it throws, something is wrong. I tried the code in Dart 2.0.0-dev.49.0, and it worked. Which version of Dart are you using (`dart --version`) and how are you running it?

If you run your program as `dart --checked program.dart` then you will get the type error when you try to assign an `int` to a `BigNum` variable.