# How to create a BigInt in Dart

Tags: dart, integer, bigint

I'm trying to create a BigInt in Dart just to learn about BigInt.

I tried this

```dart
var x = 237462836487263478235472364782364827648632784628364;
```

But that gives an error because the compiler thinks its an int but greater than 64 bits.

Then I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074813/how-do-we-cast-an-int-as-a-bigint-in-dart-2), so I tried this:

```dart
var x = BigInt.from(237462836487263478235472364782364827648632784628364);
```

That still gives the same error:

> The integer literal 237462836487263478235472364782364827648632784628364 can't be represented in 64 bits.
>
> Try using the BigInt class if you need an integer larger than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 or less than -9,223,372,036,854,775,808.

I thought I was using the BigInt class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source code, it turns out the way to create a `BigInt` from a number literal is to parse it from a string:

```dart
final x = BigInt.parse('237462836487263478235472364782364827648632784628364');
final y = BigInt.from(1);
final z = x + y;
// 237462836487263478235472364782364827648632784628365
```